# SetUp/TearDown methods in sahi tests using junit framework

Tags: java, junit, installation, sahi, teardown

Is it possible to place the setup/teardown methods using JUnit framework in a single class (which would be my baseclass) so on test runs they methods are always called first/last? it would be in a similar way to which nunit tests can be structured

currently the only way I can get my tests to kick off is if I have the setup/teardown methods within the same class as my tests are (which is something I wan't to avoid, to keep my test classes tidy)

example I would hope to set up;

```
public class baseclass
{
    @Before
    public void setUp
    {}

    @After
    public void tearDown
    {}
}

public class tests
{
    @Test
    public void test1
    {
        // test content here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this test and see the sequence of events

```
class Test1 {
    @Before
    public void setUp1() {
        System.out.println("setUp1");
    }
}

public class Test2 extends Test1 {
    @Before
    public void setUp2() {
        System.out.println("setUp2");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as your `test` class extend your `baseclass`. 
For instance:

- Suite

  ```
  @RunWith(Suite.class)
  @SuiteClasses(Tests.class)
  public class AllTests {

  }
  ```
- BaseClass

  ```
  public class BaseClass {

      @BeforeClass 
      public static void beforeAll() { 
      }

      @Before
      public void setUp() { 
      }

      @After
      public void tearDown {
      }

      @AfterClass 
      public static void afterAll() { 
      }
  }
  ```
- Tests

  ```
  public class Test extends BaseClass {

      @Test
      public void test1() {
      }

      @Test
      public void test2() {
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks Albert!

New to Java so figuring out inheritance was confusing me :)